# How to determine if to print or not to print out data in a array list based on if the same value has been printed before

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have look for a while and worked on this but I just can't figure out the best way of doing this. 
So in my android app i have two arraylist. One that holds the days and another that holds items that were bought on those days. What I want to do is to print this out into a textview for display.
I am thinking of using a string to holds the current date and see if it equals to the pervious date. If it does then don't print it just print the "" and the item right next to it. The list are based off the times not the dates. So the array list of dates are identical to each other in some cases. So I would like for it to be something like this

```
2016/12/1  Item1
           Item2
           Item3
2016/01/3  Item1
           Item2
2016/02/25 Item1
```

but right now its like this

```
2016/12/1  Item1
2016/12/1  Item2
2016/12/1  Item3
2016/01/3  Item1
2016/01/3  Item2
2016/02/25 Item1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> myDates = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> myProducsts = new ArrayList<String>();

TextView dates, products;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dates);
    products = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.products);

    //for total of 5 orders
    myPurchase first, second, thrid, fourth, fifth;

    myDates.add("2016/3/30:");
    myDates.add("2016/3/30:");
    myDates.add("2016/3/30:");
    myDates.add("2016/3/30:");
    myDates.add("2016/3/30:");
    myDates.add("2016/4/8:");
    myDates.add("2016/4/8:");

    myProducsts.add("Item1");
    myProducsts.add("Item2");
    myProducsts.add("Item3");
    myProducsts.add("Item4");
    myProducsts.add("Item5");
    myProducsts.add("Item6");
    myProducsts.add("Item7");

    for(int i = 0; i < myDates.size(); i++)
    {
        String next = myDates.get(i);
        String nextPro = myProducsts.get(i) + "\n";
        dates.append(next + nextPro);
    }



}
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your for loop logic to the following.

```
String currentDate = "";
for(int i = 0; i < myDates.size(); i++)
{
    String next = myDates.get(i);
    String nextPro = myProducsts.get(i) + "\n";
    if (currentDate.equals(next)) {
        dates.append(nextPro);
    } else {
        dates.append(next + nextPro);
        currentDate = next;
    }
}
```

You'll have to deal with some string formatting to get the output lined up like you want.

Comment: Almost.  `currentDate` should start as `null`.  See my suggested edit.

Comment: Oh good catch. (Actually it should start as a blank string to avoid a null pointer :))

Comment: Actually, I would invert the equals check.  Given that next is non-null, check if `next.equals(currentDate)` instead of `currentDate.equals(next)` ... now, no NPE.

Comment: True, either way is just fine.

Comment: Thank you guys that worked like a charm. I just didn't know how to deal with checking to see if it was printed. Thank you once again